# Idiom for explaining something to someone who clearly knows the topic (probably better than you)

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom/phrase which would mean that someone is trying to explain something to someone who obviously knows how it's done. It would be like a maths student trying to teach/explain to his maths professor in his university how to do calculus - he clearly knows it better than you!

My language has for example "nie ucz ojca dzieci robić" - that translates as "don't teach a father how to make kids" - is there an equivalent in English?

Comment: There’s ***preaching to the choir***

Comment: @Jim: Nah. That has an entirely different meaning.

Comment: @Robusto - yeah, that’s why I didn’t put it as an answer.  It fits marginally with the title.

Comment: Search the term and you get the idiom: https://pl.bab.la/slownik/polski-angielski/nie-ucz-ojca-dzieci-robi%C4%87

Comment: dupe : https://english.stackexchange.com/q/163773/107198

Comment: potrzebujemy SE języku polskiego.

Comment: While there are several options at the linked question, I notice the recent coinage "mansplaining" didn't come up there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't [teach your grandmother how to suck eggs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/teach-your-grandmother-to-suck-eggs).

Comment: This is generally more rural/colloquial, but it's what I thought of first. +1

Comment: +1 because it's an exact match in traditional meaning. The only problem with it is that I think a lot of people don't know what it means. I thought it was a straight-up insult until well into adulthood (emphasis on *your grandmother sucks eggs*, along the lines of *your mother wears combat boots*) and there have been at least a couple of questions here about "this strange phrase", so it may be best to use it with a cautious eye on your audience.

Answer (score 6):

A current term is [mansplaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansplaining). Originally, this meant *by* a man *to* a woman, but the Wikipedia article suggests that it can be used more generally.

Comment: I first heard the phenomenon discussed byTom and Ray on the NPR "Cartalk" show. I cant recall exactly when but Im guessing about 2000. They used the term MES for Male Explanation Syndrome.

Comment: +1 The phrase also has a lot of snowclone potential: it can be modified to suit the situation in some obvious way. For the OP's example, perhaps ***math**splaining*.

Comment: Snowcloning is a lot more likely than using "man"splaining in a context other than a man to a woman